# How to remove qq-uploader from selected table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a file-upload feature in my MVC 3 application.
I have it working correctly (kinda), the problem is within the onComplete function when I try to remove the qq-uploader class, it gets removed from all the checked table cells.
The workflow would be as follows, user checks multiple check boxes the "upload file" btn appears in each row checked, but once one upload is complete in one row the 'qq-uploader class is removed from all cells not just the cell where the file was uploaded.

The table row cell in question :

```
     @if (Model.ElementAt(index).CertName != null)
             {
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).CertName)</td>
             }
             else
             {                  
                <td id ="attBtn" class="file-uploader-attachment-Class"></td>
             }
```

Script used in view :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function handleCheckbox() {
        if ($(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').removeClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");

            createUploader($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').addClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
            $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').html($('#myHTML2').html());
        }
    }

    $('tr').each(handleCheckbox);
    $('tr').on('click', handleCheckbox);

    function createUploader(container) {

        var elements = container.find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class');

        var CAL_ID = container.find(':checkbox').val()

        var row = $(this).parent();

        Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function (element) {

            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: element,
                sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
                action: '/CalibrationViewer/AttachmentUpload',
                allowedExtensions: ['xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'csv', 'txt', 'rtf', 'zip', 'zipx', '7z'],
                params: {
                    customer: CUST_NAME,
                    calibrationId: CAL_ID
                },
                multiple: false,
                debug: false,

                onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
                    alert(responseJson.msg);
                    $('.qq-uploader').remove();
                    elements.closest('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').prepend('<div class="uploadedTag"><p>Uploaded</p></div>')
                }

            });

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
  elements.closest('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').find('.qq-uploader').remove();
```